# Secure Kiali (in Istio) by source ip address

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have applied kiali in Istio 1.10.2 by using [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/1.10.2/samples/addons/kiali.yaml). Now I am trying to secure it by filtering source ip address. I tried using authorization policy but it didn't work. It keeps allowing everyone when [it should deny any request that is not in the ALLOW policy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/)

AuthorizationPolicy:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: kiali-ingress-policy-allow
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kiali
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        remoteIpBlocks: ["10.43.212.247/32","10.43.212.242/32"]
```

VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "kiali.myinternaldomain.local"
  gateways:
  - istio-system/my-internal-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kiali
        port:
          number: 20001
```

Installed ISTIO using default profile and these extra parameters:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          overlays:
          - apiVersion: apps/v1
            kind: Deployment
            name: istio-ingressgateway
            patches:
            - path: kind
              value: DaemonSet
            - path: spec.strategy
            - path: spec.updateStrategy
              value:
                rollingUpdate:
                  maxUnavailable: 50%
                type: RollingUpdate
    egressGateways:
      - name: istio-egressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          hpaSpec:
            minReplicas: 2
    pilot:
      k8s:
        hpaSpec:
          minReplicas: 2
  values:
    gateways:
      istio-ingressgateway:
        autoscaleEnabled: false
        env:
          ISTIO_META_HTTP10: '1'
    pilot:
      env:
        PILOT_HTTP10: '1'
```

Comment: How did you setup your cluster - some bare-metal solution or cloud provider? Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: Bare-metal. Kubernetes 1.20.6

Comment: Which [installation configuration profile](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/) did you use? Do you have already any [AuthorizationPolicy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#AuthorizationPolicy) applied in your cluster? How did you setup LoadBalancer on your bare metal solution? Could you share logs from the Istio ingress gateway pod (get pod name using `kubectl get pods -n istio-system` command and then `kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-{random} -n istio-system`)?

Comment: Why are using`remoteIpBlocks`, not `IpBlocks`? Did you check source IP addresses that are coming to the cluster? From where the requests are - outside a cluster or from other pods? Could you setup TCPdump to observe incoming IP addresses? Could you get the name of the kiali pod and check logs using following command: `istioctl proxy-config log "$pod" -n istio-system --level rbac:debug`?

Comment: Also please answer previous questions.

Comment: Let me correct - could you setup your proxy config to logs RBAC error using `istioctl proxy-config log "$pod" -n istio-system --level rbac:debug` command and then check logs using `kubectl logs -c istio-proxy` in pod related to Kali?

Comment: Also please answer previous questions.

Comment: I installed ISTIO using default profile and some extra parameters (edited the original post)

Comment: I do have other AuthorizationPolicies applied in the same cluster in other namespaces and they are working fine.

Comment: Node are running in VMs and the LoadBalancer is a fortigate firewall.

Comment: Logs for ingressgateway are [here](https://pastecode.io/s/pcriaoig)

Comment: I have changed from remoteIpBlocks to IpBlocks but it still allows traffic from ip addresses other than 10.43.212.247 and 10.43.212.242 to kiali. My computer is 10.43.212.246

Comment: Couldn't execute that `# istioctl proxy-config log "$pod" -n istio-system --level rbac:debug` , got the error: 
`Error: failed to execute command on Envoy: failed retrieving: resource name may not be empty in the "istio-system" namespace`

Comment: Could you please follow [this documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#ip-based-allow-list-and-deny-list) and let us know the results? Take a look especially that AuthorizationPolicy is using different selector than your policy - it's matching labels for `app: istio-ingressgateway`. Please try it and let know the results.

Comment: For getting logs: please run first command `kubectl get pods -n istio-system`, you should get list of the pods. Look for the pod starting with name `istio-ingressgateway-{some-letters-and-numbers}`, copy this pod name and use it in the command `istioctl proxy-config log {copied-pod-name}-n istio-system --level rbac:debug`, then please run `kubectl logs {copied-pod-name}`. Check from which IP address requests are coming. Please let us know the results.

Comment: You need also to setup option to keep the source IP addresses. Instructions are [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#source-ip-address-of-the-original-client). Keep in mind that there are different instructions for different LoadBalancers. Please let us know the results.

Comment: Please give more information about your cluster - which solution did you use (kubadm, kubespray etc.). Which Kubernetes version are you using? These IP addresses (["10.43.212.247/32","10.43.212.242/32"]) are from the same network, right? Could you please describe your current network design? Which exactly LoadBalancer solution are you using?

Comment: Additional information for getting logs - please first setup [IP based allow](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#ip-based-allow-list-and-deny-list), and then setup additional logs.

Comment: This is the output for `kubectl get pods -n istio-system -o name -l istio=ingressgateway | sed 's|pod/||' | while read -r pod; do kubectl logs "$pod" -n istio-system ; done | grep kiali | tail` -> https://pastecode.io/s/ru7gb425 . My ip address is 10.43.212.246 (showed in logs)

Comment: After setting rbac:debug to both of my ingress gateways, log seems to be the same: https://pastecode.io/s/b8zjg0fw

Comment: I already have thus set to my ingressgateway service: `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`

Comment: We are running k8s 1.21.7 and nodes are running in VMs and the LoadBalancer is a fortigate firewall.

Comment: I use kubeadm. Those ip addresses  (["10.43.212.247/32","10.43.212.242/32"]) are from the same network. They are addresses for the hosts allowed to open kiali. My ip address is 10.43.212.246 and should be blocked and not be able to open kiali.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to setup working `ALLOW` policy in the Istio 1.10.2 on [GCP VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute), the cluster is setup using kubeadm with Calico CNI plugin. I used this documentation - [Ingress Gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/).

Note: I changed `istio-ingressgateway` service type to `NodePort` service instead of `LoadBalancer`, but this does not matter in this case.

---

My network design is following:

- First VM - Kubernetes node - 10.xxx.0.2 address
- Second VM - 10.xxx.0.3 address
- Third VM - 10.xxx.0.4 address - this address will be in the ALLOW policy

I deployed the following NGINX service and deployment...

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deply
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

... and following gateway and virtual service definitions:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "my-test.com"
  gateways:
  - gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx-svc 
        port:
          number: 80
```

Take a look at the `nginx-svc` service name in virtual service definition (you should use the one that you want to configure).

From every VM in the network I can run following command:

```
user@vm-istio:~$ curl 10.xxx.0.2:31756 -H "Host: my-test.com"
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

So it's working properly.

I [enabled RBAC debugging for the ingress gateway pod](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#before-you-begin)...

```
kubectl get pods -n istio-system -o name -l istio=ingressgateway | sed 's|pod/||' | while read -r pod; do istioctl proxy-config log "$pod" -n istio-system --level rbac:debug; done
```

...and I set `externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local` in service `istio-ingressgateway` to [preserve an IP address from the original client](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#source-ip-address-of-the-original-client):

```
kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}
```

In the logs of the istio ingress gateway controller I can the that requests are coming and they are being proceed:

```
kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-5d57955454-9mz4b -n istio-system -f
...
[2021-11-24T13:39:47.220Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - via_upstream - "-" 0 615 1 0 "10.xxx.0.3" "curl/7.64.0" "69953f69-8a46-9e2a-a5a7-36861bae4a77" "my-test.com" "192.168.98.74:80" outbound|80||nginx-svc.default.svc.cluster.local 192.168.98.72:60168 192.168.98.72:8080 10.xxx.0.3:55160 - -
[2021-11-24T13:39:48.980Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - via_upstream - "-" 0 615 1 0 "10.xxx.0.4" "curl/7.64.0" "89284e11-42f9-9e84-b256-d3ea37311e92" "my-test.com" "192.168.98.74:80" outbound|80||nginx-svc.default.svc.cluster.local 192.168.98.72:60192 192.168.98.72:8080 10.xxx.0.4:35800 - -
```

Now, I will apply IP-based allow list to allow only second VM address to host `my-test.com`:

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-policy
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        ipBlocks: ["10.xxx.0.4"]
    to:
    - operation:
        hosts:
        - "my-test.com"
```

On the VM with address 10.xxx.0.4 curl is working as before, but on the VM with address 10.xxx.0.3 we can notice following:

```
user@vm-istio:~$ curl 10.xxx.0.2:31756 -H "Host: my-test.com"
RBAC: access denied
```

So it's working as expected.

In the logs of the istio ingress gateway controller we can notice that request is denied (look for the logs related to the RBAC):

```
kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-5d57955454-9mz4b -n istio-system -f
2021-11-24T14:05:11.382613Z     debug   envoy rbac      checking request: requestedServerName: , sourceIP: 10.xxx.0.3:55194, directRemoteIP: 10.xxx.0.3:55194, remoteIP: 10.xxx.0.3:55194,localAddress: 192.168.98.72:8080, ssl: none, headers: ':authority', 'my-test.com'
':path', '/'
':method', 'GET'
':scheme', 'http'
'user-agent', 'curl/7.64.0'
'accept', '*/*'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.xxx.0.3'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'http'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-request-id', '63c0f55c-5545-92a0-80fc-aa2a5a63bf04'
'x-envoy-decorator-operation', 'nginx-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:80/*'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata', '...'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata-id', 'router~192.168.98.72~istio-ingressgateway-5d57955454-9mz4b.istio-system~istio-system.svc.cluster.local'
, dynamicMetadata: 
2021-11-24T14:05:11.382662Z     debug   envoy rbac      enforced denied, matched policy none
[2021-11-24T14:05:11.382Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 - rbac_access_denied_matched_policy[none] - "-" 0 19 0 - "10.xxx.0.3" "curl/7.64.0" "63c0f55c-5545-92a0-80fc-aa2a5a63bf04" "my-test.com" "-" outbound|80||nginx-svc.default.svc.cluster.local - 192.168.98.72:8080 10.xxx.0.3:55194 - -
```

Especially this part:

```
[2021-11-24T14:05:11.382Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 - rbac_access_denied_matched_policy[none]
```

It clearly shows that our policy is working.

Example of the log that allowed our request:

```
2021-11-25T10:58:34.717495Z     debug   envoy rbac      enforced allowed, matched policy ns[istio-system]-policy[ingress-policy]-rule[0]
[2021-11-25T10:58:34.717Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - via_upstream - "-" 0 615 25 23 "10.xxx.0.4" "curl/7.64.0" "889e3326-093c-94b1-b856-777c06cbe2b7" "my-test.com" "192.168.98.75:80" outbound|80||nginx-svc.default.svc.cluster.local 192.168.98.72:46190 192.168.98.72:8080 10.xxx.0.4:37148 - -
```

What's important:

- make sure that in logs of the pod `istio-ingressgateway-{..}` you can notice the source IP address of the other VM so the policy can allow / block
- my advice is to setup AuthorizationPolicy **for external traffic** at the edge of service mesh - which is istio ingress gateway, that’s why my AuthorizationPolicy is using “selector” matching label `app: ingress-istio-ingressgateway` (not the kiali)
- [use a proper type of IPs - `ipBlocks` vs `remoteIpBlocks`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#ip-based-allow-list-and-deny-list). Base on your setup, it should be `ipBlocks`:

> **When to use  `ipBlocks`  vs.  `remoteIpBlocks`:** If you are using the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header or the Proxy Protocol to determine the original client IP address, then you should use `remoteIpBlocks` in your `AuthorizationPolicy`. If you are using `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`, then you should use `ipBlocks` in your `AuthorizationPolicy`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. As you said, the key modification was to change selector to `istio-ingressgateway` . I will put my final YAML as solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as noted by @mikolaj-s, was to change selector to istio-ingressgateway. I was trying to use selector kiali because that's the way I use in other namespaces for other workloads. Even though app label is configured perfectly:

```
> kubectl get services -l app=kiali -A
NAMESPACE      NAME    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE
istio-system   kiali   ClusterIP   10.97.200.171   <none>        20001/TCP,9090/TCP   13d
> kubectl get pods -l app=kiali -A    
NAMESPACE      NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-system   kiali-6fbbc6d8c9-rctjh   1/1     Running   0          47h
```

I also changed the logic to use action "DENY", source "notIpBlocks" and specify the hostname.

Final AuthorizationPolicy that works is:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: kiali-ingress-policy-allow
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  action: DENY
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            notIpBlocks: ["10.43.212.247/32","10.43.212.242/32"]
      to:
        - operation:
            hosts:
              - kiali.myinternaldomain.local
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
```